# Use CCLabelBMFont inside UIViewController Inside Node

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'am doing a game, when the player lose, and screen of Game Over appears. But my Game Over screen its in a UIViewController. I call it in my Director, and alls right.

The Game over screen appears like overlay in the game

But i am using Custom Fonts, and in my Game Over screen I want to use it. But how could I use only "CCLabelBMFont" in the Game Over.

I think a way (no the better one). Its that you print in a bigger z-index than the Game Over the text I want it with "CCLabelBMFont". But I want to have all the stuff of Game Over in the GameOver.m

What could I do? Thanks to everybody.

Comment: If you're going to mark him down, it would be polite to leave a comment so he knows why.

Answer (score 0):

To present anything from Cocos2D on top of a UIKit view, you'll have to make the Cocos2D view transparent and introduce a dummy view. You can't achieve this effect with the z order because that affects only the nodes in Cocos2D's OpenGL view.

To make the Cocos2D view transparent you need to change the color depth to 32 bit (RGBA8888) from the default 16-Bit mode in the EAGLView initialization (app delegate). Then setup the view hierarchy with a dummy view, so that you can actually add UIKit views in the background and the Cocos2D view as the foremost view.

The basic approach is to do this in your app delegate didFinishLaunching method:

```
UIView* dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
[dummyView autorelease];
[dummyView addSubview:[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView];
rootViewController.view = dummyView;
[window addSubview:rootViewController.view];

// make the cocos2d view transparent:
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].opaque = NO;
```

From then on you can use the dummyView to manage the view hierarchy. For example, when you add your game over view to the dummyView, you want to call sendToBack on it so that it is drawn behind the cocos2d view.

The entire process with all things to consider is described in detail in my [Learn Cocos2D Game Development book (2nd Edition)](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/).

Comment: Yes i think that, but, My problem its that the game its based on the CCDirector, and then I add the Game Over Screen and inside the Game Over class i want to add a CCLabelBMFont.

I know i could add the Label in the Game with a z bigger than the Game Over. But I want to have it all organized and get everything in the Game Over Class